# PowerShell cmdlet to get a name of recently zipped folder?

Tags: powershell

I have tried

```
$latest1 = gci $path -Include *.zip| ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1
```

but `$latest1` is giving blank output.

Comment: if it is a zip file, is it also a directory? psiscontainer will filter out resutls from get-childitem which are not directories (folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Include` switch will **only work** if the path ends in `\*` or when used together with the `-Recurse` switch.
Since in your case, you are only looking for zip files, I would use the `-Filter` parameter.

```
$latest1 = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter '*.zip' -File | 
           Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

For PowerShell version below 3.0 use

```
$latest1 = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter '*.zip' | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | 
           Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

If a zip file was found in the path, `$latest` should now be a FileInfo object with properties like `FullName`, `BaseName` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your where-object filter or removing it

```
$latest1 = gci $path -Include *.zip| ? { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1

$latest1 = gci $path -Include *.zip| | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1
```

Comment: Tried ur answer..Its still showing up blank
PS > $latest1 = gci $path -Include *.zip| ? { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1
PS > write-host $latest1

PS >